# Why is my UITableView Grey?

Tags: uitableview, swift

I'm trying to print a `UITableView`, but a grey rectangle appears instead.

My `UITableView` is inside a `UIView` on my Storyboard and I'm using a custom `UITableViewCell`

Do you have any idea ?

[Here's a gist of my code](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-besnard/f617408b425b43ffdd1a)

[image]

Comment: It's not what it seems. What you see is a dozen of separators. Make sure your cell's height is not zero.

Comment: I was stuck with this since 30 minutes. Thank you !

Comment: That left inset was a clue. ;)

Comment: I'm new in iOs I didn't notice it :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the tableView background color and your cell background color on your storyboard.
I don't see anything wrong in your code.